# nth-child of list of a particular class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have following type of list

```
<ul id="mylist">
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='abc'>first</li>
  <li></li>
  <li class='abc'></li>
  <li class='abc'></li>
  <li class='abc'>last</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the first and last child of ul whose class is 'abc'. I used following js code

```
var start = $('#mylist li.abc:first-child');
var end = $('#mylist li.abc:nth-child');
```

but unfortunately I am not getting the desired results.. :( Please guide me where I am wrong, thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try

```
var start = $('#mylist li.abc:first');
var end = $('#mylist li.abc:last');
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, but its not working :( But if I use `var start = $('#mylist li.abc');` for start then it works

Answer (score 2):

Try the following instead:

```
var start = $('#mylist li.abc:first');
var end = $('#mylist li.abc:last');
```

See it visually here: http://jsfiddle.net/BTwFU/1/

Comment: Thanks GregL, I tried same answer from Nicola, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

you may try this out:

```
var start = $('#mylist li.abc').first();
var end = $('#mylist li.abc').last();
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried:

```
var start = $('#mylist li.abc').first();
var end = $('#mylist li.abc').last();
```